# Javascript scientific notation floats vs integers explained

Tags: javascript

I am working with js numbers and have lack of experience in that. So, I would like to ask few questions:
2.2932600144518896
e+160
is this float or integer number? If it's float how can I round it to two decimals (to get 2.29)? and if it's integer, I suppose it's very large number, and I have another problem than.
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't JS only have 1 number type?

Comment: @Carcigenicate yep https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type

Comment: Yes it cannot be stored precisely in js, so one could call it float. `Math.round` ?

Comment: I am not interested in type, but what's the value of this. is it 2.29 or some bilion integer

Comment: `2.2932600144518896e+160` is equivalent to `2.2932600144518896 * Math.pow(10,160)` and approximately 229 followed by 158 zeroes i.e. very big.

Comment: What has this to do with JavaScript? The ["e-notation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) is used in C, Java, Perl, Python, ...

Comment: @Andreas the question was specific to JS. Yes the notation is used elsewhere but the way JS handles it would be very different given the number's size

Comment: Do you want the number or the string representation of the number with "2 decimals"?

Comment: I asked is this 2.29 and something or big big integer that's where I am not clear

Comment: @phuzi The question was/is: "is it 2.29 or some bilion integer" and that's not a JavaScript problem...

Comment: note: don't add space between `e` and last digit... and try it yourself ! `console.log( 2.298896e+16);` so any deduction?

Comment: @Vikast see my comment above

Comment: @Andreas fair enough

Comment: I see, not 2.29 but big number, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript only has one [Number type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type) so is technically neither a float or an integer.

However this isn't really relevant as the value (or rather representation of it) is not specific to JavaScript and uses [E-Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation) which is a standard way to write very large/small numbers.

Taking this in to account `2.2932600144518896e+160` is equivalent to `2.2932600144518896 * Math.pow(10,160)` and approximately 229 followed by 158 zeroes i.e. very flippin' big.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, as said in comments, this is a Number.

What you can do if you want the number (not its string representation):

```js
var x = 2.2932600144518896e+160;
var magnitude = Math.floor(Math.log10(x)) + 1;
console.log(Math.round(x / Math.pow(10, magnitude - 3)) * Math.pow(10, magnitude - 3));
```

What's the problem with that? Floating point operation may not be precise, so some "number" different than 0 should appear.

To have this number really "rounded", you can only achieve it through string (than you can't make any operation).

Comment: As long as the numbers can be represented as integers in the number of bits available in the mantissa, and their exponents are positive and more or less match, operations on them must be precise as long as the result can still fit into the mantissa without rounding. That is, `1.0 + 10000.0` should be precise, while `0.000001 + 0.00000001` will have a rounding error typical for the binary floating point representation.